# Touchscreen not working at the center in Asus Zenfone 2

Tags: touchscreen

It's been a week, and I've been facing a touch related issue in my Asus Zenfone 2 running Android 5.0. My smartphone's touch is not working at the center. Touch test showed blank area at the center. How to solve this problem? Is it a software or a hardware specific problem?

This happened after my phone got wet in rain: I used [Screen Touch Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp.stest) to test touchscreen:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

My device is neither rooted, nor is under warranty. I did factory reset but it didn't help.

Comment: Since your did a Factory reset and it dint work, I guess its a hardware problem. Temporarily you can use the one-hand mode in your notification screen where your can resize/move your screen to access your phone.

Comment: It's happen to me to, here is the solution, try it, it's works...
https://youtu.be/iFNAomLnECc

Answer (score 0):

Your touchscreen hardware is broken. You need to take it to your local repair shop and have the touchscreen replaced.

If it were new (and therefore faulty when sold) or still under warranty, the manufacturer would be more than happy to replace it: I have friends who've experienced the same kind of problems and got replacements, even on cheap unbranded tablets.